# Stored Procedure com baixa performance

Tags: oracle, pl-sql, procedure

Estou com problema no Oracle, onde tenho duas procedures que são executadas uma seguida da outra.
Onde na primeira `procedure`, eu tenho um cursor que faz `insert` em uma tabela. 
Este insert tem aproximadamente **30 milhões de registros**, que são inseridos em um tempo
rápido e aceitavel.

Mas quando a procedure seguinte é executada, a que faz o update, está sim demora. Em uma ultima execução demorou cerca de 38 horas. E esta possui somente um cursor de `update`, menor que o primeiro e ao executar o cursor separadamente, ele é executado em menos de um minuto.

Um detalhe, é que quando as procedures estão sendo executado, e vejo que a segunda `procedure` está "travada", se eu paro a execução, dou um `analyze table`, e a executo somente a segunda procedure novamente, ela é executada normalmente, demorando cerca de 1 ou 2 horas para completar.

Alguém tem ideia de como me ajudar?

Comment: Pode passar alguma coisa do código das suas procedures e das tabelas relacionadas? Como são os índices delas ?

Comment: Passar alguma coisa do código é meio complicado pois é regra de negócio da empresa. Mas básicamente na primeira procedura é um cursor de insert, e na segunda um de update. Os indices estão ok. O problema é que quando executado automatico a segunda procedure que faz o update, demora anos. Se eu executo cada uma separadamente, elas executam rápido.

Comment: **Primeiro**: precisa fazer o `UPDATE` dessa forma? Não tem como já inserir os dados com os valores corretos ou então dar um `UPDATE` geral? **Segundo**: o problema pode ser a carga transacional acumulada. Já pensou em fazer o update em blocos, fazendo `COMMIT` a cada `N` registros?

Comment: @EricoSouza Anonimize o código. Não precisa postar aqui exatamente o código da sua empresa, mas algum código reduzido que represente o que você está tentando fazer.

Comment: @utluiz Sim, eu preciso fazer o update dessa forma. Pois somente alguns registros são atualizados conforme a regra de negocio exige, e conforme suas condições. O commit é realizado a cada 100 mil registros. Estou utilizando também bulk collect

Comment: Vc ta usando SQL o PL/SQL? Porque quando vc usa um SQL cursor dentro de PL/SQL, as informaçoes precisam ser "filtrada" do lado SQL, depois copiada do lado PL e depois as dados vão voltar, de PL -> SQL. Tambem, PL precisa parar, esperar a respota de SQL, etc... mesmo se do ponto de vista "humano", tuda parece certo, dentro do computador, e muito pesado!

Comment: @Peter uma coisa que andei conversando com os colegas de trabalho que entendem melhor que eu, porem ainda também não sabem a solução com certeza, é o seguinte, que após a inserção dos 30 milhões de registro na tabela, o Oracle parece não entender que esta tabela já tem os registros nela, para que o update seja realizado. Por isso se pararmos o processo e fazer um ANALYSE TABLE, e executar a proc novamente, ela é executada normalmente e rápido.

Comment: @Erico, ou, outra opçao, o Orale sabe que ele tem os dados, mas ele não tinha preparado os index. Entao, podemos imaginar que vc esta fazendo um "update" numa tabela que nao tem os index prontos, o que demora muito. Uma olhada na documentaçao Oracle, mostra que, quando vc vai fazer insert, e update cada vez ele vai modificar o index. Parece ter um "tips", indicando que para acelerar pode ser melhor destruir o index, fazer os insert/update e depois, re-construir à index: "Dropping index before a mass update and rebuilding them afterwards can improve performance significantly".

Comment: @Peter, sabe me dizer se isso pode afetar outro usuário em outra sessão, caso esteja por exemplo utilizando um select na tabela onde vou destruir o indice?

Comment: Provavelmente, mas no mesmo tempo acho que quando vc esta fazendo o update que demora, isso afeta tambem os outros usuarios. A diferencia vai ser o tempo. Precisa testar. O que e cada vez bem dificil quando o sistema e usada.

Comment: Tentou coletar estatíscas desta tabela após o insert massivo ?

Comment: @Motta sabe me dizer como consigo fazer esta verificação? Ou alguma referencia de como eu possa aprender? Obrigado

Comment: EXECUTE DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS       https://community.oracle.com/thread/639184

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução que encontrei, junto a um colega de trabalho, que funcionou a melhora da perfomance, levando cerca de 1 hora para processar todas os registros. O que antes chegou a demorar cerca de 28 horas.

A solução que testamos e funcionou foi alterar **SORT_AREA_SIZE** da sessão. O padrão do Oracle é 65536 bytes, segundo a [documentação do Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams232.htm#REFRN10206)

Alteramos para um valor 10 vezes a mais, indo para 655360 bytes.